# PowerShell - Extract Specific Values from CSV and Export to New CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, split, text-extraction

I have a CSV file named csvfile1.csv - the file has one column named "profile" and the value for each row is generally in this format (some rows do not contain all these values):

```
{'lastName': 'lastName value', 'manager': 'manager value', 'secondEmail': 'secondEmail value', 'managerId': 'managerId value', 'title': 'title value', 'login': 'login value', 'employeeNumber': 'employeeNumber value', 'division': 'division value', 'firstName': 'firstName value', 'mobilePhone': 'mobilePhone value', 'organization': 'organization value', 'department': 'department value', 'email': 'email value'}
```

**I'm trying to use PowerShell to extract the 'manager value' and 'email value' and export it to a new csv, but I'm stuck**.  I don't know the best way to approach it - regex/split?  What makes it more complicated is that there is only one column and everything is stuffed into that one column so it make it difficult to parse out.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like json.  You might be able to do something like this `Get-Content csvfile1.csv | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ConvertFrom-Json`

Comment: So the Csv has Json in one of it's columns? If so, what Daniel mentioned should work otherwise post the Csv as plain text